# Disable schema auto refresh when connecting via mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

I have a lot of tables in my Database and every time I connect via MySQL Workbench, the schema starts to auto refresh and start fetching tables. However this process takes long time and after some time it says could not be fetched.

Due to this auto fetching I cannot immediately start executing scripts. I have to wait for the auto fetch to timeout before I can do my stuff. How do I disable this auto fetching/refresh of the schema upon connecting via MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL Workbench only loads the default or last used active schema at startup. There's no way to disable that (how can it show a list of db objects otherwise?). However, you can make a small db (say mysql or temp) your default, which loads quickly (you can set a default in the connection settings).

But you have to use fully qualified identifiers to access your objects in the other schema then.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench is certainly a workhorse, but can sometimes feel a little bloated and glitchy. What version are you using? Version 6 moved a lot of tasks to a background thread, this may solve your issue if your still running 5.

Consider using the leaner, but older MySQL Query Browser for basic tasks; http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/query/

Comment: Although Query Browser was a fine piece of work (I was one of the authors) it is not recommended to be used with newer MySQL servers. MySQL Workbench is really the right tool.